# Creating a function when user clicks on element to toggle another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I use a lot of "when user clicks on element then another element will be displayed as visible/hidden... aka toggle".

So I'm trying to make a general function to abide the DRY principal.

Before jumping into the code, I just wanted to state that there are still bugs. I just want to know before continuing if writing a function like the one below is necessary or if I should just ignore the DRY in this case and have lots of separate toggle functions. Or if it's necessary, would there be a more efficient method?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7YGv3/1/)

***Brief Description of Code**

-There are 4 parameters

- The first two are mandatory, the last two are optional
- The index parameter is a string of numbers ex. "1.0","1"
- The reason I need the last two parameters is because I have elements that can't be easily
  targeted. For example, they don't have an #id. So to grab those generic elements, I use getElementsByTagName
- Then I'll use the index parameter to get the element in the array.
- index parameter: The number before '.' is the index of the clickElement
  and the number after '.' is the index of the toggleElement. clickElement = 1. toggleElement = 0.

```
function toggleClick(clickElement, toggleElement, condition, index) { 
    var toggleIndex;
    var clickIndex;

    if(condition === false){
        if(index.indexOf('.') != -1){
            //indexOf returns -1 if '.' is not found. 
            // Checks to see if two index is entered
            indexArray = index.split('.');
            clickIndex = indexArray[0];
            toggleIndex = indexArray[1];
            clickElement = document.getElementsByTagName(clickElement)[clickIndex];
            toggleElement = document.getElementsByTagName(toggleElement)[toggleIndex];
        }else{
            //If there is no '.', that means only one index was entered.
            // By function requirement, it should be the index of clickElement

            clickElement = document.getElementsByTagName(clickElement)[index];
        }
    }
    $(clickElement).click(function(){
            $(toggleElement).toggle();
        });
    }
```

This is one of my first functions, and so I need some guidance on whether I'm writing bad code. Yes, this might be broad because there may be many different ways to write this function.  But I just need to know if there's a more efficient way or if my way is okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you're trying to be flexible here, but your approach comes at a cost: *The API isn't understandable.* I can see you're trying to toggle the second parameter element with the first parameter as the toggle,  But I don't understand exactly how the third or fourth works, if it's even needed. It's also a weird convention.

Reflect on these three things here:

- The point of *programming* is having stuff done easier.
- The point of a *programming language* is to do programming in that's understandable to humans.
- The point of an *API* is to "lift" (abstract) the programming language.

Fail on one of those, and the rest before it breaks apart (and things like the great flood, alien invasions, world war 3 happen). So before you design an API, or even just a function, think about the users/developers using it. It might be you in the distant future.

---

Now off to your code. Seeing you're using jQuery, a similar feat could have been done through this piece of code. I do notice you said *"elements that can't be easily targeted. For example, they don't have an #id."* - jQuery still can target them using your standard [CSS selectors (here's a few to remember)](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048), and some [custom jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) (which I think is a superset of CSS selectors, if I'm not mistaken).

. The `:eq()` part is optional, but it does what you need, select specific indices.

```
// Assuming delegation for future elements
$(document).on('click','li:eq(0)',function(){
  $('div:eq(0)').toggle();
});
```

It's as simple as "Get the first of all `<li>` and toggle the first of all `<div>`". Simple enough. But what if you wanted *your own simple function for it* and not some jQuery mashup that is copy-paste bait? [Something like this could be done too](http://jsfiddle.net/7YGv3/2/):

```
;(function ($) {
  $.fn.customToggle = function (trigger, target, event) {
    // Let's add a twist, custom functions. Assume click if not defined.
    event = event || 'click';
    this.on(event, trigger, function () {
      $(target).toggle();
    });
  }
}(jQuery));

// Still, future-proof, let's support future elements
$(document).customToggle('li:eq(0)', 'div:eq(0)');
$(document).customToggle('li:eq(1)', 'div:eq(1)','mouseover');
```

There you have it. Now you'd wonder *"That's not any different from my code"* - exactly. It's the same. However, there's one important bit I changed - it's the way I selected the elements and indices. I used CSS selectors - which every developer who came across CSS or jQuery should already know.

---

Here are other suggestions on how you could structure the API:

```
// Chained:
$(document)
  .customToggle('li:eq(0)', 'div:eq(0)')
  .customToggle('li:eq(2)', 'div:eq(4)')
  .customToggle('li:eq(3)', 'div:eq(9)')

// Map
$(document).customToggle({
  'li:eq(0)' : 'div:eq(0)',
  'li:eq(2)' : 'div:eq(4)',
  'li:eq(3)' : 'div:eq(9)'
});
```

Comment: aww darn it, I can't help but feel a bit disappointed that my function isn't comprehendible but I understand why. Much thanks to both of you who answered! I'll definitely be using this much better written code. P.S.  I love the twist with the custom function.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like this function will cause more problems than it's supposed to solve. Here is why:

A function should do a specific task, that is self descriptive by the function name. Having a function that does a lot of different things depending on it's parameters is not easy to use and read.

Unfortunately `toggleClick` does not do what it says, and it uses up brain matter every time you have to use it.

If I somehow ended up having to work with this code i'd have to run the `if` statements in my head before writing them as parameters to the function.

> If the user clicks the first element, I should toggle the third child of that element,
>  
>   but only if this variable is TRUE, otherwise the parent itself should toggle instead

If I had to use something like this, it is such a specific use case that I'd propably write the code I just thought about, instead of trying to figure out what this function does.

What I'd do:

If I can edit the markup, or the interacting elements are not decided dynamically, I'd set IDs to the elements I want to interact and do a simple

```
$('#myelement').on('click', function(){
      $('#target_element').toggle();
});
```

It might be 3 lines long, but you know what it does the moment you read it. If you want to mimic the use of your `toggleClick` you can try this instead:

```
// When I click the 2nd child of #my_element...
$('#my_element :eq(0)').on('click', function(){
    // Toggle the fifth child of the #target_element
    $('#target_element :eq(4)').toggle();
});
```